# Geodesics connecting two points in the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Let $\mathbb{H}^2$ be the upper sheet of the hyperboloid defined by $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ in three-dimensional Minkowski space $(\mathbb{R}^3, g_M)$, where $g_M = \text{diag}(1,1,-1)$. In other words, consider the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane.

Given two points $p,q$ on the hyperboloid, I would like to derive a parametric equation for the geodesic connecting $p,q$.

So far, I was able to specify the plane containing $p,q$ and the origin by $\pi : (p \times q) \cdot x=0$, because $(p \times q)$ is a normal vector to the plane and the plane must contain $(0,0,0)$. The equation of the geodesic is now the intersection of this plane with the hyperboloid. Since $(p \times q)$ can't be parallel to the $z$-axis, we may assume w.l.o.g. that the $x$ coefficient of the plane is non-zero. Solving for $x$ using the plane equation and substituting this into the hyperboloid equation gives a complicated equation in $y$ and $z$.

I also thought of using the geodesic characterisation $p\cosh(t)+v\sinh(t)$ for a unit tangent vector $v$, but here the trouble is finding the correct $v$ so that the geodesic will pass through $q$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: The dot and cross product are the Minkowski versions, not Euclidean? <> In any case, one approach is to map $p$ to $(0,0,1)$ by an isometry $T^{-1}$, find the geodesic to the image of $q$, and map this geodesic by $T$ to get the desired geodesic.

Comment: To determine the plane equation I was purely relying on Euclidean geometry. From my understanding, the intersections of Euclidean planes passing through the origin with the upper sheet of the hyperboloid are geodesics in the hyperboloid model. The origin, together with $p$ and $q$ determine a unique Euclidean plane, which has a non-empty intersection with this hyperboloid. Please correct my understanding if this is wrong!!!

Comment: Your understanding is correct; the "Minkowski" dot and cross products merely have the advantage of of yielding normal vectors and planes adapted to the hyperboloid model. :) Pat Ryan's _Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry_ contains a nice treatment. <> (+1) to your answer, incidentally!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Andrew's comment, I have figured it out.

Suppose we have points $p = \begin{pmatrix} \sinh(v)\cos(\theta)\\\sinh(v)\sin(\theta)\\\cosh(v)\end{pmatrix}$ and $q = \begin{pmatrix} \sinh(u)\cos(\phi)\\\sinh(u)\sin(\phi)\\\cosh(u)\end{pmatrix}$.

We first rotate $p$ into the $x$-$z$-plane by applying the isometry

$R_{-\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(-\theta) & -\sin(-\theta) & 0\\
\sin(-\theta) & \cos(-\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Next, we apply the isometry

$S_{-v} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cosh(-v) & 0 & \sinh(-v)\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sinh(-v) & 0 & \cosh(-v)
\end{pmatrix}$,

which is essentially a shift along the hyperboloid.

Lets call the composite isometry $T^{-1} = S_{-v}R_{-\theta}$.

Observe that this isometry acts on p as $p \mapsto T^{-1}p = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

We need to figure out its action on $q$, which is easily calculated to be

$q \mapsto T^{-1}q = \begin{pmatrix}
\sinh(u)\cosh(-v)\cos(\phi-\theta) + \cosh(u)\sinh(-v) \\
\sinh(u)\sin(\phi-\theta) \\
\sinh(u)\sinh(-v)\cos(\phi-\theta) + \cosh(u)\cosh(-v) \\
\end{pmatrix}$

The tangent plane $T_{(0,0,1)}\mathbb{H}^2$ has orthonormal basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$. Let $\Pi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ be the projection onto this tangent plane.

Let $v = \frac{\Pi T^{-1}q}{\lvert\lvert \Pi T^{-1}q \rvert\rvert }$, where the norm is taken with respect to the Minkowski metric. Thus, $v$ is a unit vector in $T_{(0,0,1)}\mathbb{H}^2$.

It suffices to find the geodesic starting at $(0,0,1)$ in the direction of $v$. By the formula given in the original question it is given by $\gamma(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\cosh(t) + v\sinh(t)$. It is easy to see that this curve is unit-speed. It is also easy to calculate that, in order for the curve to terminate at $T^{-1}q$, we must have $t \in [0, \text{arccosh}(-p\cdot q)]$, where the dot product is with respect to the Minkowski metric, so we have derived the distance between points $p$ and $q$ along the way.

The final answer is given by inverting the isometry:

$T\gamma$ is the cuve we are looking for.